# Zend_Session_Namespace not working as expected

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

After creating a namespace, if I try to add a value to it, the variable has the particular value, but not the session with the namespace. But, if I create some variable, that is a key for an array, and add the value to it, it is saved to the session. To illustrate my point:

```
public $submitUser;
public function init ()
{
    $this->submitUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('submitUser');
    Zend_Session::rememberMe(60*60*24*7);
}

public function selectUserAccount ($username)
{        
    $returnArray = array(
        'name' => 'Man', 
        'surname' => 'With a surname',
        'username' => $username
    );
    $this->submitUser->user = $returnArray;
}
```

Inserts into the session

```
'submitUser' => 
    array
      'user' => 
        array
          'name' => string 'Man' (length=3)
          'surname' => string 'With a Surname' (length=14)
          'username' => string 'jpeiseni' (length=8)
```

But

```
public function selectUserAccount ($username)
{        
    $returnArray = array(
        'name' => 'Man', 
        'surname' => 'With a Surname',
        'username' => $username
    );
    $this->submitUser = $returnArray;
}
```

Doesn't set the variables in the session

This is a small nuisance, that I can probably live with, but I would like to know if there is a reason not to allow the namaspace to have a value for it self, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this makes sense, what you're effectively doing is this:

```
$this->submitUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('submitUser');
$this->submitUser = $returnArray;
```

so you create an instance of Zend_Session_Namespace and then you replace it with a completely different variable.

Perhaps something like this would make more sense (depending on what this code is for):

```
$this->submit = new Zend_Session_Namespace('submit');
$this->submit->user = $returnArray;
```

Comment: Oh darn it... I was so immersed in the building, that I didn't look at the simple PHP underneath. That makes way much sense. In the end I went with `$this->submitUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('submitUser');
        $this->submitUser=$this->submitUser->submitUser;` So it works, but still is shorter than original.

Comment: do you mean `$this->submitUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('submitUser'); $this->submitUser=$this->submitUser->user;`

Comment: Actually, the same thing. You just are using the array key `user`, I'm using `submitUser` again.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
public function selectUserAccount ($username)
{
    $returnArray = array(
        'name' => 'Man',
        'surname' => 'With a Surname',
        'username' => $username
    );
    $this->submitUser->applySet('array_merge', $returnArray);
}
```